# How to display the HTTP status code with message in an Ajax fail function

Tags: http, web, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

I am doing server side validation. I want to display the error message in toster. Now I am able to display the status code, but I have to display the error message also:

```
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "please enter the name");
```

My Ajax code is:

```
statusCode: {
        201 
            toastr.success('Added Successfully');
        }
    }
}).fail(
         function (xhr, textStatus, err) {                    
             toastr.error(err);                    

         });
```

In toaster it is showing a bad request but I want to display the message ("please enter the name") also. I tried the following link, but it did not work for me. When I tried it in postman service I got a message.
     http://forums.asp.net/t/1781489.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [ReasonPhrase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.reasonphrase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var error = "please enter the name";
var response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
response.ReasonPhrase = error;
return response;
```

Comment: Hi aliostad is it paossible to display two error message ?i have tried but it is taking first alert only.

Comment: @aliosted."please enter the name"+"contact",now i did like this.it is showing in one alert.is it possible to display in 2 alert

Comment: @Hemanth set the error to "please enter the name + contact" ??

Comment: ya i set the error like above.but i want two error message.1) "please enter the name",2) "contact" ,is it possible?

Comment: do the processing on the client side (split errors). If not successful ask another question.

Comment: ya i tries it.its working.but it will work only fr two messages.more den that its nt possible.